# How to put each item into p tag + clear innerHTML at end

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dom-manipulation

I can't seem to correctly figure out how to both: add a p tag to each index && clear the element of all text, once it has reached the end of the array. I've tried various methods at this point and seem to only ever get part of my desired outcome right.

Looking to make it as dynamic as possible.

```js
const myText = ['hi there', 'my friend', 'how are you', 'today', '?']
let i = 0

function createModal(buttonId) {
  buttonId.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(
      myText[i] == undefined ? "" : myText[i], i++)


    document.getElementById('append').appendChild(textNode)
  })
}


createModal(test)
```

```html
<button id="test" type='button'>(keep clicking)</button>
<div id="append"></div>
```

Comment: add your html...

Comment: Sorry about that, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to remove all the paragraph text if the limit of the array reaches, until then you want to add a paragraph element containing text in div
this is your updated code

```
    const myText = ['hi there', 'my friend', 'how are you', 'today', '?']
    let i = 0

    function createModal(buttonId) {

        buttonId.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (i == myText.length) {
                const requiredElement = document.getElementById('append');
                requiredElement.replaceChildren();
                i = 0;
                return;
            }
            let paragraphElement = document.createElement('p');
            paragraphElement.textContent = myText[i];
            document.getElementById('append').appendChild(paragraphElement);
            ++i;
        });
    }

    createModal(test);
```

```
    <button id="test" type='button'>(keep clicking)</button>
    <div id="append"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly. This is almost there, I'm just getting some bugs happening once remove() gets initiated. Here is a code pen to see what I mean: https://codepen.io/bb-bell/pen/MWjPQYO

Comment: @bbBell updated my code, this is much efficient than previous version

Comment: Great ~ Thanks so much @mss ! I know my example + explanation was a bit confusing and all over the place. But this is it. Appreciate it.

Comment: @bbBell, Glad to be of help:)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a good english but maybe this is what you want

```js
const myText = ['hi there', 'my friend', 'how are you', 'today', '?'];
let i = 0;

 function createModal(buttonId) {
    buttonId.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(myText[i] == undefined ? "" : myText[i], i++)
        if(i>myText.length){document.getElementById('append').innerHTML = "";}
        
        let pTagNode = document.createElement("p");
        pTagNode.appendChild(textNode);
        document.getElementById('append').appendChild(pTagNode);
    })
 }


 createModal(test)
```

```html
<button id="test" type='button'>(keep clicking)</button>
<div id="append"></div>
```

if you want it to start over again, you can use this

```js
const myText = ['hi there', 'my friend', 'how are you', 'today', '?'];
let i = 0;

 function createModal(buttonId) {
    buttonId.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(myText[i] == undefined ? "" : myText[i], i++)
        if(i>myText.length){document.getElementById('append').innerHTML = "";i=0;}
        
        let pTagNode = document.createElement("p");
        pTagNode.appendChild(textNode);
        document.getElementById('append').appendChild(pTagNode);
    })
 }


 createModal(test)
```

```html
<button id="test" type='button'>(keep clicking)</button>
<div id="append"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "clear innerHTML at end", but to append `<p></p>` rather than just text, you just need to use `document.createElement`

```js
const myText = ['hi there', 'my friend', 'how are you', 'today', '?']
let i = 0

 function createModal(buttonId) {
    buttonId.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let textNode = document.createTextNode(
            myText[i] == undefined ? "" : myText[i], i++)
        
        let pNode = document.createElement("p"); // Create a <p> node
        pNode.appendChild(textNode); // Put your text node inside the <p> node

        
        document.getElementById('append').appendChild(pNode)
    })
 }


 createModal(test)
```

```html
<button id="test" type='button'>(keep clicking)</button>
<div id="append"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do?
As long as i is less than 5 which is the length of myText array, it creates the code.

```js
const myText = ['hi there', 'my friend', 'how are you', 'today', '?']
    let i = 0

    function createModal(buttonId) {
      buttonId.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (i < myText.length) {
          let textNode = document.createTextNode(
            myText[i] == undefined ? "" : myText[i], i++)

          const p = document.createElement('p');
          p.appendChild(textNode);

          document.getElementById('append').appendChild(p);
        }

      });
    }

    createModal(test)
```

```html
  <button id="test" type='button'>(keep clicking)</button>
  <div id="append"></div>
```